# Fishy version of Kodaira embedding theorem !

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, complex-geometry

Is there any theorem characterizing those sypmlectic manifolds that can be embedded symplectically in projective space equipped with Fubini-Study symplectic form?

Comment: You should also see this mathoverflow question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/59733/projective-embedding-of-symplectic-manifolds

Answer (score 8):

According to this paper:  http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9811167.pdf, it is a theorem of Gromov and Tischler (op cit) that EVERY compact symplectic manifold is a symplectic submanifold of complex projective space.

Comment: (Every compact symplectic manifold with integral symplectic class, that is.) 

Comment: Thanks Tim, what about the symplectic orbifolds. I mean is there an embedding theorem for them in some suitable weighted progective spaces?