# Is a symplectic submanifold of a Kähler manifold Kähler?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Is a symplectic submanifold of a Kähler manifold Kähler?

That is, if $X$ is a Kähler manifold with symplectic form $\omega$ and $i:Y\hookrightarrow X$ is an embedded submanifold such that $i^*\omega$ is symplectic, is $Y$ a Kähler submanifold of $X$?

Comment: According to this question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59733/projective-embedding-of-symplectic-manifolds, the Kodaira-Thurston manifold is a symplectic submanifold of $\mathbb{P}^5$. Not only is this not a Kahler submanifold, it is not even Kahler (for any metric).

Comment: Another comment. The fact that Y is symplectic is an open condition on the embedding of Y in X, it will be preserved by perturbation... so a deformation of a Kähler submanifold (among embeddings which are not necessarily holomorphic) will remain symplectic if the deformation is small enough.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No. In $\mathbf C^2$ with standard 2-form and complex structure, the real span of $U=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and $V=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}i\\1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ is a symplectic but not complex (hence not Kähler) subspace, since
$$
\omega(U,V)=1,
\qquad
JU=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}i\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right)\notin\operatorname{span}_{\mathbf R}(U,V).
$$

Comment: Also, Kostant and Sternberg have a nice paper ([1982](https://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=661285)) on homogeneous symplectic, non-Kähler submanifolds of $\mathbf{CP}^n$.